# Is there a Power BI Map Visual that can do this?

Tags: powerbi

The following is a screen shot from a Tableau report and I need to recreate this in PBI:

[image]

The map consists of two different data sets. The five square data points are latitude and longitude values based on a filter set. That's easy to reproduce. The 11 shaded areas represent 11 different zip code areas. For each of the 11 zip code areas, I need the area of the country represented by the zip code to be highlighted and shaded by a certain color gradient that is dependent upon a measure. For example, the orange shaded area is zip code 37122 near Nashville, TN.

Is anyone aware of PBI map visual that can do this? I've spent about two hours reviewing a few but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that a Filled Map visual in Power BI can do exactly this.